# How to collect jars with sources from projects in dependencies list?

Tags: gradle

I have a simple multi-project build:

```
root
|___ a
|___ b
|___ c
```

`build.gradle` in root project:

```
subprojects {
    task jarSources(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
        classifier = 'source'
        from sourceSets.main.java, sourceSets.main.resources
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` in project `a`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':b')
    compile project(':c') 
}

task archiveDependencySources(type: Zip) {
    ...
}
```

Task `archiveDependencySources` is intended to collect all jars with sources from projects on which project `a` depends. Is there a standard way to do this job?

So far I found the solution that looks a bit ugly:

```
def allJarSourcesTasks = []
for (def dep : configurations.compile.dependencies)
if (dep.hasProperty('dependencyProject'))
    allJarSourcesTasks << dep.dependencyProject.tasks['jarSources']

archiveDependencySources.dependsOn allJarSourcesTasks
archiveDependencySources.from allJarSourcesTasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work (not sure about the `null` argument):

```
allJarSourcesTasks = configurations.compile.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "jarSources").getDependencies(null)
```

For `dependsOn`, `.getDependencies(null)` could be omitted, but I believe it is needed for `from`.